# How to set an accessibilityIdentifier on a UITabBar's buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitabbar

Like the title states, how do you programmatically set the `accessibilityIdentifier` on a `UITabBar`'s buttons? I'm currently trying to set the `UITabBarItem`'s `accessibilityIdentifier` before adding it to the tab bar, but that doesn't seem to carry through to the button.

How do you go about setting an `accessibilityIdentifier` on the actual buttons that are displayed on the page?

Comment: `UITabBarItem` implements the `UIAccessibilityIdentification` protocol. If you are seeing an issue, make sure to open a bug report with Apple, and post the number here so people can clone it.

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem with SwiftUI. Putting the `accessibilityIdentifier` in a different place fixed it:

```
TabView(selection: $tabSelection) {
   // ...
   // ...
   .tag(0)
   .tabItem {
       Label("Catalog", systemImage: "list.dash")
       .accessibilityIdentifier("tabCatalog") // <-- Works here
   }
   .accessibilityIdentifier("tabCatalog") // <-- Doesn't work here
}
```

Comment: how do you go to tabCatalog in the xctest?

Comment: @AntonTropashko Strangely, SwiftUI converts it to a button behind-the-scenes, so this works: 
`let tabCatalog = app.buttons["tabCatalog"]`
`sleep(1)`
`tabCatalog.tap()`

Answer (score 2):

When I ran into the same problem, I ended up setting the identifier on the underlying UITabBarButton (not sure if apple would object to that though..)
You need to setup your UITabbar with your UITabBarItem and their identifiers first, then:

```
//Set the tabbar items and their identifiers first, then, copy them on the underlying UITabBarButton using this code
int index = 0;
for (UIControl *control in controller.tabBar.subviews)
{
    if ([control isKindOfClass:UIControl.class] && index < tabBarController.tabBar.items.count)
    {
        control.accessibilityIdentifier = controller.tabBar.items[index].accessibilityIdentifier;
        index++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For UI tests, I'm doing it as follows, in a view controller:

```
self.tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier = @"NewRecordTab";
```

in Swift that would be

```
self.tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "NewRecordTab"
```

Comment: For some reason when I set tabbar item on the root view controller of the tab, ui test don't see this identifier

Comment: doesn't work for me either. Since the UITabBarItem isn't something actually displayed on screen, it is only a container for the information displayed on the button.

Answer (score 0):

The `tabBarItem` property is not an inheritor of `UIView`. It is only used by the `UITabBarController` class when adding a child tab to it. After the `tabBarController` has loaded and initialized the tabs, it is useless to change the values of the `tabBarItem` property. Therefore, it is critically important where exactly you set the value of `tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier`.

The only working way is to set a value in the controller initializer as shown in the example below:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

   init() {
      super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
      self.tabBarItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "myTabIdentifier"
   }

}
```

If you set the value of this property elsewhere (for example, in the `viewDidLoad` method), then `UITabBarController` will never know about it, because the `viewDidLoad` method is called after `tabBarController` has initialized its tabs.

Alternatively, if the solution above does not suit you, you can interact with tabs using the tab index as follows:

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
app.tabBars.buttons.element(boundBy: tabIndex).tap()
```